# firebase count online users and update in global counter

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I want to count online users in firebase and store the value in firebase under online_users, when user in connect to app to increment the online_users and when user disconnect from app to decrements. 
I build firebase function

```
export const countOnlineUser = functions.database
.ref('/UserStatus/{uid}')
.onWrite((change, context) => {
    var collectionRef = change.after.ref.parent;
    var countRef = collectionRef.child('online_users');

    let increment = 0;
    if (change.after.exists() && !change.before.exists()) {
        increment = 1;
    } else if (!change.after.exists() && change.before.exists()) {
        increment = -1;
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    // Return the promise from countRef.transaction() so our function
    // waits for this async event to complete before it exits.
    return countRef.transaction((current) => {
         console.log(current)
        if (current == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            return (current || 0) + increment;
        }

        }).then(() => {
            return console.log('Counter updated.');
        });

});
```

client side update user each time user is connect to app

```
constructor() {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            if (user) {
                const { uid, phoneNumber } = firebase.auth().currentUser._user
                 UserStore.setUID(uid)
                 this.setListenConnection()

            }

        })


    setListenConnection = async () => {

        this.userStatusDatabaseRef = firebaseRef(`UserStatus/${UserStore.user.uid}`)

        firebaseRef('.info/connected').on('value', async connected => {
            if (connected.val() === false) {
                return
            }

            await firebaseRef(`UserStatus/${UserStore.user.uid}`).onDisconnect().remove()
            this.userStatusDatabaseRef.set({ state: 'online', last_changed: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() }, { merge: true })
        })
    }
```

[image]

I have some issues with these functions
sometimes the online_users is negative and I want to prevent it.
sometimes I get in transaction current is null.

How can I fix it?

Comment: You seem to have gotten the basic counter from the [functions-samples repo](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/child-count/functions/index.js)), which is known to be pretty solid. The key to fixing the problem is to figure out when it exactly happens.

Comment: One mistake in your current code is that you assume there is a single connection per user. That is not at all guaranteed. A user could use the app on multiple devices, or could even end up with multiple connections (only one active connection though) on a single device. I'd highly recommend following the pattern from the documentation, which uses a push ID for each connection: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-sample.

Comment: Precisely what does "connected to app" mean?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I solved the issue of connect with multiple devices in other way by save uid with unique device id. this way user can't user in multiple devices with other devices. when he try, it throws him from second device and sign out with firebase. I'm trying to understand what not good with my functions I wrtoe. I checked the example you published in functions-sample and it seem like exactly what I did..

Comment: @RonRoyston "connected to the app" is when user open the app and he already has connected with firebase means he has unique uid from firebase

Comment: If the code is the same between the sample and what you use, the difference must be elsewhere. You'll have to figure out steps to reproduce the problem, so we can look at the same problem you have. I know this may be difficult, but without it we're just clutching at straws here.

Comment: An alternative is to take a different approach to the counting. The functions sample you copied tries to count deltas, so counting +1 and -1 as items are added/deleted. You can also simple recount all child nodes whenever there is a change, by triggering on `/UserStatus` and then simply writing the value as `countRef.set(change.after.numChildren())`. It's much simpler and (while not as efficient) will scale find to a few hundred thousand online users (as long as you keep little data per used).

Comment: can you show me how with my current code? this is what you mean? https://pastebin.com/s5xpxJGq

Answer (score 0):

[Performance Monitoring](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318039) exposes sessions or current users but it appears to be only for mobile apps (ios/android).

> #### Google Analytics for Firebase data collection The type of information collected through the Google Analytics for Firebase
>
> default implementation includes:
>
> - Number of users and sessions
> - Session duration
> - Operating systems
> - Device models
> - Geography
> - First launches
> - App opens
> - App updates
> - In-app purchases

As for Cloud Functions, Check out [Writing and Viewing Logs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs). If it's doable, this would be the API.

Comment: Hey ron, sounds like great way to do that. I looked on react-native-firebase docs and I don't see any way to get the number of users and session with firebase analytics. docs link https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase-docs/blob/master/docs/analytics/reference/analytics.md